# How to catch the {'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas required exceeds allowance (0)'} exception in we3.py?

Tags: gas, web3.py, gas-estimate, exceptions

I'm using the `estimate_gas` method to get the gas estimate for the tx that I'm sending and in case balance < gas estimate I wanna trow an exception.

```
    try:
        gas_estimate = self.w3.eth.e(tx_params)
        logger.info(f"Gas estimate: {gas_estimate}")
        tx_params["gas"] = int(gas_estimate * gas_multiplier)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(
            f"Error estimating gas: {e}",
        )
        return None
```

The problem is that I cannot catch the exception properly and get traceback. How can I catch the exception?

Comment: Your code isn't totally clear - what does `self.w3.eth.e` do exactly?
An `RPCResponse` that contains an error won't necessarily throw a python error that you can catch. You can just check if `error` is in the response, then do what you want with it.